# Creating a multilevel grid with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a requirement where I need to create a multi level grid. Where when user clicks on checkbox a child grid will be opened. Please look at HTML shown below:

```html
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>check</th>
       <th>Result</th>                                            
     </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><a>test</a></label></td>
           <td> Description</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="12">
              <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><a>testing</a></label></td>
                    <td>description</td>          
                 </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Something similar as shown here: http://dojo.telerik.com/uQEx.
I have written angular code for it. And I have wrapped tr in *ngfor to show high level. Please look at code shown below:

```
<tr *ngFor = "let data of values">
  <td>
     <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">
     </label>
     <a (click) = "getTerms(data.id)">{{data.id}}</a>
  </td>
  <td>{{data.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

I need to append another list when I click on a tag that is `data.id`. I am confused how to append response of sub terms in html. Please let me know if you have any suggestion. Also I don't want to use any plugin for it.

**EDIT:**

The response I am getting on page load is:

```
[
 {id:1, desc:'test', level: 0},
 {id:2, desc:'testing',level: 0}
]
```

And now when I click on id =1 column I am sending service request:
/get/Term/1
And I am getting response:

```
[ {id:5, desc: 'test test', level: 1} ]
```

In the similar way now if I click on id=5 I will get response as:
[ {id:8, desc: 'test test test', level: 2} ]

Hope now its clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tavish the question is: What do you have? What do you want obtain?
...
As you are add items to your data, one idea is that
At first you have

```
this.data=[
 {id:1, desc:'test', level: 0},
 {id:2, desc:'testing',level: 0}
]
```

If click "1" you received

```
[ {id:5, desc: 'test test', level: 1} ]
```

It's good that you change your data adding "children". So in getData(data.id,i)

```
//we pass as argument the index too
getData(id:number,index:number)
{
     this.httpClient.get("url"+id).subscribe(res=>{
           this.data[index].children=res
     }
}
```

So, your data becomes

```
this.data=[
 {id:1, desc:'test', level: 0,children:
   [ {id:5, desc: 'test test', level: 1} ]
 },
 {id:2, desc:'testing',level: 0}
]
```

Now you only need to using two *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let level0 of data;let index=i">
    {{level0.id}}{{level0.desc}}{{level0.level}}
    <button (click)="getData(level0.id,index)">click</button>
    <div *ngFor="let level1 of level0.children">
       {{level1.id}}{{level1.desc}}{{level1.level}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This idea work if you need fews levels, but if you have more that two or three levels can be a nightmire

With more levels you need, when received the data push in data but add the id_parent

```
getData(id:number)
{
     this.httpClient.get("url"+id).subscribe(res=>{
           res.forEach(x=>{
             //¡¡IMPORTANT!! not {parent.id,..x}
             this.data.push({...x,parent:id})
           })
     })
}
```

So, your data becomes

```
this.data=[
 {id:1, desc:'test', level: 0}
 {id:2, desc:'testing',level: 0}
 {id:5, desc: 'test test', level: 1,parent:1}
]
```

if you have a function like

```
listData(parent:number)
{
    return (parent)? this.data.filter(x=>x.parent==parent)
                   : this.data.filer(x=>!x.parent)
}
```

Your *ngFor can be like

```
<div *ngFor="let level0 of data;let index=i">
    {{level0.id}}{{level0.desc}}{{level0.level}}
    <button (click)="getData(level0.id)">click</button>
    <div *ngFor="let level1 of listData(level0.id)">
       {{level1.id}}{{level1.desc}}{{level1.level}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have update my answer too. What number of levels are you think you can have?

Comment: That I can't get, as data is dynamic. We can have as many number of levels.

Comment: Then take the last option and create dinamicaly component. e.g. https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

Comment: Check this link it might help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular`

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal, it's not necesary create a dinamic template. You can do some like the example I write. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

Example to show a "iterate" component

```
//app.component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
  <app-app-children [children]="data"></app-app-children>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  isdisabled:boolean=false;
  data=[{id:1},
        {id:2,
            children:[{id:4},{id:5},{id:6,
                      children:[{id:9},{id:10}]}]},
        {id:3,
             children:[{id:7},{id:8}]}
        ];

  constructor(){}
}


//app-children
@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-children',
  template:`
  <p>
  app-children works!
</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of children">{{item.id}}
  <div *ngIf="item.children">
      <app-app-children [children]="item.children"></app-app-children>
  </div>
</div>`
})
export class AppChildrenComponent {

  constructor() { }
  @Input() children

}

//If whe can have a table, We can change the template like:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-app-children',
    template: `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>#</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of children">
        <td>
           <div>
            {{item.id}}
           </div>
           <div *ngIf="item.children">
            <app-app-children [children]="item.children"></app-app-children>
           </div>
        </td>
    </table>
    `,
    styles:[`
      table, th, td {
         border: 1px solid black;
         margin-left:2rem;
      }
      `
     ]
  })
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't have data of children's at page load. I will be getting data for id when I click on it.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal, I put as you can implement add "children" to your data when you make "click" :(

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I just saw that and was thinking about which approach should I use.

Comment: I have code as `<table><thead><th></th></thead><tbody><app-app-children [children]="data"></app-app-children></tbody>`. ISsue is using this way all columns are coming in 1st th only. Any solution?

Comment: Using the code shown above, there will be multiple table headings that can created. Can you please share plunk link if possible? Thanks!

Comment: sorry I'am in hurry. by the way, try using css app-children {
    display: inline-block;
}, and use ng-container if you don't want to create extra divs

Comment: I have created recursive component but I have question on appending childrens dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506270/how-to-append-children-to-object-dynamically. Can you please answer it?